# Issues sending selected rows values into a controller MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm trying to send the selected rows into a controller when I click on the button with id="send". The issue is that when I tried to send other values( in this case a number and a string) with the selected rows values, the selected rows values is sending null to the controller but the number and the string aren't null in the controller parameters.

This is my javascript code that works fine if only i send the selected rows values:

```
$('#send').click(function () {
            var items = {};
            var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
            var selectedElements = grid.select();

            for (var j = 0; j < selectedElements.length; j++) {
                var item = grid.dataItem(selectedElements[j]);
                items['grid[' + j + '].ParecidoCodigo'] = item.ParecidoCodigo;

            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Busqueda")',
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: items,

                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            })
        })
```

and this is my controller method action:

```
public ActionResult Index(MarcaParecido[] grid)
{ ... }
```

Everything works fine until now.But when I tried to send another values like this:

```
$('#send').click(function () {
            var items = {};
            var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
            var selectedElements = grid.select();
            var enviarDest = $('#destinatario').val();
            var marca = $('#numMarca').val();

            for (var j = 0; j < selectedElements.length; j++) {
                var item = grid.dataItem(selectedElements[j]);
                items['grid[' + j + '].ParecidoCodigo'] = item.ParecidoCodigo;

            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Busqueda")',
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: { items, marcas: marca, destinatario: enviarDest },

                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            })
        })
```

The selected rows values is sending me null, but the others values aren't null

This is my controller now:

```
public ActionResult Index(MarcaParecido[] grid, string marcas, string destinatario)
{...}
```

I tried with JSON.stringify too but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If items is a collection of the key/value pairs that you are sending to the server, add the two additional parameters to that, and then continue to send item the items object.  MVC should read the "grid." items as the list of items in the collection (as you have working now), and see the other two parameters in the variables you have specified:

```
items["marcas"] = marca;
items["destinatario"] = enviarDest;

$.ajax({
  .
  .
  data: items
```

Comment: Thanks, that help me a lot.

Comment: Any idea of why didn't work the way i was trying to do? Is not possible to pass a parameters that way?

Comment: Yes because you're creating an object with key/value pairs, but when the code has `data: { items, marcas: marca, destinatario: enviarDest },`, this basically constructs an object of 3 pairs, the first being an array (not sure what the property name would be) and thus doesn't serialize well.  By keeping the name/value pairs in one object, it serializes well and all is then transferred to the server in a way that MVC normally processes POST requests.